# Elastic apm, what is transaction.duration.us?

Tags: elasticsearch, nginx, elastic-apm

I'd like to measure avg request-response time for my webserver.

Apm has `transaction.duration.us` and it seems this could be the metric I'm looking for.

But I coulnd't find the documentation what it is.

Where can I find the meaning of the variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`transaction.duration.us` should indeed be what you're looking for. It's the duration in microseconds as an integer. Divide it by 1000 to get milliseconds, or by 1'000'000 to get seconds.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/server/7.9/exported-fields-apm-transaction.html#_duration_2

Comment: I have hardtime understanding difference between transaction and span.. oh well, it's a good news.

For 15 min, I have about 80k data points in apm-* , and when I filter by `url.path:*` it drops to 1k .. 

Although I think it's reasonable to assume I want to measure requests which has `url.path` . I'm little concerned because the # of event with `url.path` is so low. Do you think it's reasonable?

Comment: A transaction represents a full request/response cycle, while a span represents one thing happening during a transaction (e.g. a query to a database, or a request to an external API). You definitely should have much more spans than transactions in Elasticsearch, so that sounds good.

Comment: Do you think it's reasonable to assume that avg response time = avg `transaction.duration.us` of transactions where `url.path` exists?

Comment: you could also look at `transaction.type`, which should be `"request"` for all HTTP transactions